# subgroups generators of symmetric group

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

1. does any subset of symmetric group generated by repeated multiplication of 3 or more permutations can be generated by only 2 of them?
   (trivial cases of identity and single transpositions aside)
2. is there a way for finding such set of two permutations from bigger sets? (naive brute-force search aside)

(and, well, what is correct name and terminology for this problem?)

Comment: What do you mean by "repeated multiplication of three of more permutations"?

Comment: result of (1)(2 3 4) and (1 2 3)(4) is alternating group.
result of (1 2)(3 4) and (1 4)(2 3) is klein group rotation.

Comment: does all subgroups can be generated only by two of them? these seems trivial, but i do not know any proof of it, or of possibilities of edge-cases in here.

Comment: yes, right. counter-example for first question is (1 2), (3 4), (5 6).
and answer to second and third is "dig into k generators and group presentations".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question (1) correctly the answer is certainly *no*. For example, in $\;S_6\;$ , we have that

$$\;H:=\langle\,(12),\,(34),\,(56)\,\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$$

and this group cannot be generated by less than three elements. You can easily generalize the above to any finite number of generators.

Comment: This is an example of something, perhaps counter intuitive in group theory: A minimally $k$-generated group can have subgroups that cannot be generated by any set of $k$ elements (i.e. are minimally $k+l$ generated for some natural number $l>0$). I believe the smallest example is an order 16 group that is minimally $2$-generated but contains a copy of the elementary abelian group of order 8 in it, which is minimally $3$-generated.